# Passing a localy function to cloud function and saving on bucket

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, zip, fs

I have the following function running perfectly on nodejs localhost:

```
// index.js
const scrape = require('website-scraper');
const PuppeteerPlugin = require('website-scraper-puppeteer');
const path = require('path');
const zipFolder = require('zip-folder')

scrape({
    // Provide the URL(s) of the website(s) that you want to clone
    // In this example, you can clone the Our Code World website
    urls: ['https://appsevenpage.com/'],
    // Specify the path where the content should be saved
    // In this case, in the current directory inside the ourcodeworld dir
    directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'appseven'),
    // Load the Puppeteer plugin
    plugins: [
        new PuppeteerPlugin({
            launchOptions: {
                // If you set  this to true, the headless browser will show up on screen
                headless: true
            }, /* optional */
            scrollToBottom: {
                timeout: 10000,
                viewportN: 10
            } /* optional */
        })
    ]
}).then(() => {
    zipFolder('appseven', 'appseven.zip', function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('oh no!', err)
        } else {
            
        }
    })
})
```

In this function, i have the "directory", which is the folder where all files are saved (localy), as the print shows:

[image: enter code here]

[image]

This folder "appseven", i would like to save as a .zip file on my firebase bucket storage. As: "appseven.zip".

How could i do it using cloud functions onRequest ?!

Here is a base of code i made using cloud functions:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app')
const mkdirp = require('mkdirp')
const path = require('path')
const os = require('os')
const fs = require('fs')
const scrape = require('website-scraper')
const PuppeteerPlugin = require('website-scraper-puppeteer')

initializeApp()

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info('Hello mkdirp!', mkdirp)
  functions.logger.info('Hello path!', path)
  functions.logger.info('Hello os!', os)
  functions.logger.info('Hello fs!', fs)
  response.send('Hello from Firebase!')
  functions.logger.info('Hello path file! 1', tempFilePath)
  const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'teste')
  const tempLocalDir = path.dirname(tempFilePath)
  mkdirp(tempLocalDir).then(() => {
    scrape({
      // Provide the URL(s) of the website(s) that you want to clone
      // In this example, you can clone the Our Code World website
      urls: ['https://appseven.com/'],
      // Specify the path where the content should be saved
      // In this case, in the current directory inside the ourcodeworld dir
      directory: tempFilePath,
      // Load the Puppeteer plugin
      plugins: [
        new PuppeteerPlugin({
          launchOptions: {
            // If you set  this to true, the headless browser will show up on screen
            headless: true
          }, /* optional */
          scrollToBottom: {
            timeout: 10000,
            viewportN: 10
          } /* optional */
        })
      ]
    })
    bucket.upload(tempFilePath, {
      destination: thumbFilePath,
      metadata: metadata,
    });
    // Once the thumbnail has been uploaded delete the local file to free up disk space.
    return fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath);
  })
  functions.logger.info('Hello path file! 2', tempFilePath)
  functions.logger.info('Hello scrape!', scrape)
  functions.logger.info('Hello PuppeteerPlugin!', PuppeteerPlugin)
})
```

Appears to be working on locally storage, but i do need to close this temp folder and i need also to get this temp folder and save as .zip file.

Please help me, first function using temp storage on cloud functions (i'm using latest version of firebase, also).

Comment: If my answer helped or did not I would appreciate the feedback, please.

Answer (score 1):

I found this page in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_blob_or_file) that can help.

```
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";

const storage = getStorage();
const storageRef = ref(storage, 'some-child');

// 'file' comes from the Blob or File API
uploadBytes(storageRef, file).then((snapshot) => {
  console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
});
```

I think the zip file format would be taken as a blob object, so you can use this method to upload it to your bucket.